# Why is angularFire example deleting all of my Firebase entries?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to get a simple [angularFire example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PF32k/6/show/light/) working, and am seeing anything I add to [my synced Firebase db](https://andreystest.firebaseio.com/items) being immediately deleted. I expected the input box to sync to a string in /items/foo. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

angularFire is a little aggressive about removing items that don't match the expected data type. There's discussion about fixing this behavior on Github if you're interested, but you can work around it by explicitly specifying the data type using the 4th argument:

```js
var url = 'https://andreystest.firebaseio.com/items';
angularFire(url, $scope, 'items', '');
```

The fourth argument is an empty string, which tells angularFire that whatever is stored at the URL is a string. The default model type is an array ([]).

Edit: There seems to be some issues with jsFiddle and Angular. You are missing the ng-app and ng-controller directives which means angular is never initialized. However, even after adding those tags I can't get it to work in jsFiddle, it does work on a regular web page though. Give http://misc.firebase.com/~anant/angular-test.html a try!

Comment: Thanks! The directives are on the body and div on the page. You can add a different body tag than usual in the "Fiddle Options" on the left. angularFire doesn't seem to work in the jsfiddle preview, but it does in the separate page.

Comment: Could you link to the GitHub discussion you mentioned, please?

Comment: Also, Andrey, is this working for you now (aside from the JSFiddle issue)?

Comment: It is! And on JSFiddle, as well! Thank you kindly for the prompt responses :)